# Number of ngrams for vocabulary

Tags: natural-language

I read the great book Foundations of Statistical Natural Language Processing.
by Christopher D. Manning and Hinrich Schütze.

My question is regarding counting the number of ngrams for a given vocabulary.

For example, in the book, the given vocabulary has a size of 20000 words and the number of ngrams are as following

bigram model: $20, 000 × 19, 999 = 400 $ million

trigram model: $20, 000^2 × 19, 999 = 8 $ trillion

four-gram model: $20, 000^3 × 19, 999 = 1.6 × 10^{17}$

But why it actually so, why the last element is one less than the previous, I thought is should be simpler for bigrams just square of vocabulary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have $V-1$ word probabilities $P(w_i|\cdot)$, then the last one is simply one minus the sum of the rest. So there are only $V-1$ parameters to estimate.

Answer (score 0):

It appears he is discounting all n-grams where a word appears n times. Perhaps he has defined an n-gram to be defined in that way. Most definitions for n-grams that I have seen is word coocurrences of length n. So in that case it could be $V^n$ - although in practice this is likely to be a very loose upper bound.

Here are some of the counts of unique n-grams for wikipedia:

1gram    7955768

2gram  95650278

3gram  376671416

4gram  729036093

5gram  998402245

6gram 1162239794

7gram 1253270154

Comment: Where did you get these numbers from?